# Is the following representation of a holomorphic function only valid for values in the open unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a theorem which states:

Let $f= u+iv$ be a holomorphic function in a neighborhood $V$ of the open unit disk $\mathbb{D}$. Then the following formula holds:

$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z}u(e^{i\theta})d\theta+iv(0)
$$

According to this, the formula seems to hold for all the values in $V$ but I am not sure if this is actually right because we also have a theorem which states a similar statement for harmonic functions $u(z)$ on a neighborhood of $\mathbb{D}$ where the harmonic function can be expressed as:

$$
u(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-|z|^2}{|e^{i\theta}-z|^2}u(e^{i\theta})d\theta
$$

But in this case this formula is only valid on $\mathbb{D}$ and so I only want to know if the the theorem stated as above is right or does the formula also only hold for values in $\mathbb{D}$ like in the harmonic case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral on the right side is not defined if $|z|=1$. So we can only assert that the formula holds in the open unit disk.